# sendmail default sender

Tags: rhel, sendmail

I have a lot of servers, let's say our company network is called `Loosers`, when using this command

```
echo "Subject: testmail $(hostname)" | sendmail -v 'myemail@mycompany.com'
```

I effectively receive an email after a few minutes, but the sender is like `hostname@mail.loosers` instead of something like `noreply.hostname@mail.mycompany.com`.

Since my predecessor stupidly set the domain to something specifically related to my company, I suppose it is possible to change this email.  I browsed my server in `/etc/mail/*` , then the manual of sendmail, then the Internet in the search of the configuration of `sendmail`.  Nowhere can be found the string `looser` or `mail`.  I cannot grasp where my predecessor configurated this stupid default sender of `sendmail`.

How can I configure the default sender used by the bash command `sendmail`?

Comment: “the bash command sendmail” – That’s not a Bash command but most likely belongs to the postfix package. In that case you can set a custom envelope from-header using the ``-f`` argument.

Comment: Look at the main.cf config file in /etc/postfix

Comment: @RamanSailopal there is no `/etc/postfix` directory.

Comment: @phg the idea is not to use the -f flag...

Answer (score 0):

Default mail depend upon the sender account : for `root` -> `root@hostname.mycompany`

If the email is changed, this can only happen on minedefang or postfix server.  Revew the configuration of your relais servers.